# Support for muliple table ids through javascript method

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following method to read header names in a table and put in excel. Could anyone let me know how to modify this to support multiple tables with header info and data.
i.e. how to modify to pass table id. "headers" is the id for "th" tag in code.

```
function write_headers_to_excel() 
{
  str="";
  var myTableHead = document.getElementById('headers');
  var rowCount = myTableHead.rows.length;
  var colCount = myTableHead.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("th").length; 

  var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
  var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
   ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;

  for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) 
  {   
   for(var j=0; j<colCount; j++) 
   {           
      str= myTableHead.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("th")   [j].innerHTML;
    ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1,j+1).Value = str;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, so I'm guessing at what you want. Assuming your current function works as is, you can just take out the hard-coding of the table's ID and pass it in as a parameter:

```
function write_headers_to_excel(tableID)  {
   var myTableHead = document.getElementById(tableID);
   // rest of your function as is
}
```

Then call it once for each table, though that will create a new ExcelSheet for each table.

If the idea is for all of the tables to be added to the same ExcelSheet you can pass an array of table IDs to the function something like the following. I've kept the basic structure of your function but moved the variable declarations out of the loops (since that what JavaScript does behind the scenes anyway), deleted your `ExcellApp` variable since it wasn't used, and moved the `getElementsByTagName` call out of the inner loop.

```
write_headers_to_excel(["headers1","headers3","headers7","etc"]);

function write_headers_to_excel(tableIDs)  {
   var myTableHead,
       rowCount,
       cols,
       t,
       i,
       j,
       rowOffset = 1,
       ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");

   ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;

   for (t=0; t < tableIDs.length; t++) {
      myTableHead = document.getElementById(tableIDs[t]);
      rowCount = myTableHead.rows.length;

      for(i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
         cols = myTableHead.rows[i].getElementsByTagName("th");
         for(j=0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+rowOffset,j+1).Value = cols[j].innerHTML;
         }
      }
      rowOffset += rowCount;
   }
}
```

(No, I haven't tested it.)

Comment: I have multiple tables in my html page. i want to export each table to a excel file. so i was using that function. My table is in format                                      <table><thead id="headers"><tr><th></th>..</tr></thead><tbody><tr>td</td>...</tr></tbody></table> . So how do i modify my code to send tableid to the function.

Comment: You're still not being clear whether you want your multiple tables to be exported to a single Excel file or to one file per table, but both are covered by my answer. My first (short) example code defines a parameter on the function which you would call by passing it a string: `write_headers_to_excel("headers");` - the second, big block of code already has an example of passing an array of strings.

Comment: I need one file per table. In the short code u passed tableId as the parameter. Thats ok. But how do i get the row length of thead and tbody tags using table id. In my code if i have only one table i was doing  like this                                                   var myTableHead = document.getElementById('headers');
  var rowCount = myTableHead.rows.length; . Now if u pass the tableid how do i do that.

Comment: In your HTML, define a unique ID attribute on each table that you want to process, then call the function once for each of those IDs. You're almost there already...

Answer (score 0):

You can get all tr elements by tag name

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');// get all rows of all tables 

 var table=0, TableRow=0;

        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

            row = rows[i];

            if (row.parentNode.tagName != 'THEAD' && row.parentNode.tagName != 'thead') {
                  table=table+1;
               // do something here for headers
            } else if (row.parentNode.tagName != 'TBODY' && row.parentNode.tagName != 'tbody')        
               {
                TableRow=TableRow+1;
              //do something here for rows
            }

        }
```